# Heroku push rejected for lack of python buildpack

Tags: python, git, heroku

I'm trying to deploy to heroku and have my requirements.txt, Procfile, and app.py file in the root directory. I created my heroku instance with `heroku create --buildpack heroku/python` but I still get

```
remote:  !     Push rejected, failed to detect set buildpack heroku/python
remote: More info: https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/buildpacks#detection-failure
remote: 
remote: Verifying deploy...
remote: 
remote: !   Push rejected to desolate-basin-41623.
remote:
```

I've gone onto several forums and can't really seem to figure out why that is. I'm also pushing from the master branch, which seems to be something people overlook.

I did, however, I initialized my git instance above the root directory.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out, it turns out that you do have to have github initialized inside of your root.